# Divs above one another

Tags: html, css, position, display

I'm trying to make a div above one another with descriptions next to each of the divs. The divs keep wrapping to one another when resizing the window.

Right now I have the two divs with display: inline-block. The two descriptions are also in their own divs, but using padding to make sure they're positioned correctly (which seems incorrect). I've included an example image of what I am trying to achieve.
I've been self-teaching HTML/CSS so any help would be appreciated!

Here's a simplified version of the code:

The CSS for calc1 and calc2 are the same, as well as the CSS for calc1-desc and calc2-desc.

```css
.calc1 {
  width: 22%;
  margin: 5%;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.calc1-desc,
.calc1-desc ul {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 3.5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div class="w-calc1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calc1.js"></script>
  </div>
  <div class='calc1-desc'>
    <ul></ul>
  </div>


  <div class="calc2">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calc2.js"></script>
  </div>
  <div class='calc2-desc'>
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

(I'm trying to make it a split-page kind of view) [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzr8J.png)

Comment: Just added it, thanks!

Comment: Put your code in a snippet (I am on my mobile).

Comment: You can use a table, perhaps?